# Creating follow menu in Joomla

Tags: menu, joomla

I would like to create this kind of "follow" menu, so customer can return on those links with just clicking on it.[image]

Does anybody now is there any module that do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a built in module. In the module manager, select new module, then find Breadcrumbs and put it in the module position of your choice.